# PowerShell script to reset AD account when checked if it exists or not

Tags: powershell, if-statement, active-directory

I don't think I'm far away, however the first if Statement doesn't work, the reset works if the username is correct, however I want the script to validate whether AD username is correct before doing the reset. What do I need to change?

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  
$username = Read-host "please enter users AD username"  
If ($username -eq $null) {"$username does not exist in AD"}  
Else {"User found in AD"}  
$myinformation = get-aduser $username -properties *  
Set-ADAccountPassword $username -NewPassword $newpwd -Reset -PassThru |    Set-ADuser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False  
Read-host "Password reset successfully"
```

Comment: Your first `if` statement only validates if there has an username been entered with `Read-Host` at all. It does not check if the user exists in Active Directory.

Comment: How would I change this

Answer (score 0):

Update this line:

```
If ($username -eq $null) {"$username does not exist in AD"}
```

to:

```
try {
Get-ADUser $username -ErrorAction Stop
} 
Catch {"$username does not exist in AD"}
```

or:

```
if (!(Get-ADUser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $username})) {"$username does not exist in AD"}
```

like TobyU commented, your `$username` not validating if the user exist in AD, the replacement line I suggested validate it, which means if `$username` not exist (`!` short for `-not`) print 'does not exist' etc.

Comment: This will not work because it will throw a terminating error if the user is not found, so your script block won't execute. This needs to be changed to `Get-ADUser -filter {SamAccountName -eq $username}` for this logic to work as that will return `$null` if it finds nothing.